# Angular 1.4.9 methods do not work with IOS

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs

I have an app that is a kiosk.  The Kiosk can be used in multiple locations and will be specific to only that location based on the Id of said location. The Kiosk is first started from a page that lets the kiosk manager to select the location.  The kiosk will refresh approx. every 2 minutes if the screen is idle it then reloads the welcome page for the location selected from the launch of the Kiosk. This behavior will happen no matter what page the Kiosk is on, i.e. welcome screen, the page that allows the end user to check in, the page that allows the user to select the reason they are visiting. The following code works with Edge, IE 11 and Chrome however with an IOS device it does not function as expected.  IOS devices send the browser back to the page that is used for the location kiosk manager to select their location and start the Kiosk.

```
function startKioskOver() {
  //only redirect if we have a location param
  if ($routeParams.selectedLocationId > 0) {
  datacontext.resetKiosk();
  datacontext.getServiceQueueByLocationId($routeParams.selectedLocationId);
  $location.path("/" + $routeParams.selectedLocationId + "/" + $window.indexPageGlobalRazorValues.DefaultView);
  $route.reload();
  window.location.reload();
  }
}
```

Is there an issue with the IOS browser that it does not follow the behavior of all other browsers that have been tested?  Does anyone have a work around that may help?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through the code, I found that:

```
window.location.reload();
```

was the problem. It was added by a coworker and I suspect that IOS browsers are running this async and it is getting called before the $route.reload(); was finished.